# How do I write the rules for nginx redirection

Tags: nginx, lua

demand
Use 301 redirects

Source address
http://explore.gac.one/aaa/bbb/ variable

The destination address
http://explore.gac.one/#/transaction/ variable

We need a demonstration

Answer (score 0):

Single redirect:

```
location = /aaa/bbb/ {
    rewrite .* /#/transaction/ permanent;
}
```

or

```
location = /aaa/bbb/ {
    return 301 $scheme://$http_host/#/transaction/;
}
```

For lot of redirects see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49191594/nginx-rewrite-a-lot-2000-of-urls-with-parameters/49192527#49192527) answer.

**Update**

```
location ~ ^/aaa/bbb/(.*) {
    set $rest_args $1;
    rewrite .* /#/transaction/$rest_args permanent;
}
```

or

```
location ~ ^/aaa/bbb/(.*) {
    return 301 $scheme://$http_host/#/transaction/$1;
}
```

Comment: My application was developed using react to enable hash routing, which is done for compatibility with older applications without modifying older ones. The route is still accessible

Aaa/BBB this route is followed by a variable parameter. You need to get this parameter and append it to the new route

Comment: Bonus: the argument is not in get form but in restful style