# How to block a specific URL in NGINX webserver

Tags: nginx, webserver, nginx-location, ddos, nginx-config

I want to block a specific URL but I am not able to do this.

The URL that should be blocked is `example.com/clientarea/?dxx_g=dddd`.
But the following url should still work - `example.com/clientarea`.

I tried the following:

```
location ^~ /clientarea/ {
  return 444;
}
```

But if I do this it will block all connections to /clientarea.

I hope you can help me or advise me how to make this possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `location` and `rewrite` statements test a normalized URI which does not include the `?` and anything following it.

The `$request_uri` variable contains the entire URI. Test this variable using an `if` or `map` directive.

For example:

```
if ($request_uri = /clientarea/?dxx_g=dddd) {
    return 444;
}
```

You can also use regular expressions. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#if) for more. See [this caution](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) on the use of `if`.

If you have a number of URIs to block, you should consider [using a `map`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49191594/nginx-rewrite-a-lot-2000-of-urls-with-parameters/49192527#49192527) instead.

Comment: thanks for your answer, the numbers behind ga= can be numbers. We had a DDoS attach last night with following url as this clientarea?_ga=2.224.xxx.xx.xxx

But the numbers can be different per request. I think that the best solution is to match a prefix but I am not sure if this will block the other urls and how I can achieve this

Comment: Update: We are using google analytics and they attacked us with ?_ga= url so the scenario is to block this kind of request of our website is under attack.

Comment: Are you trying to block *any* URI with a `_ga` parameter? Or just those that begin with `/clientarea`?

Comment: It should block URI with _ga parameter since this was used to attach our website. But since it can be unique after the ga= it should block everything everything if we are under attach with ga tracking links

Comment: `if ($arg__ga) { ... }` (that's two underscores) should match any URI with a `_ga` parameter which is not empty and not a `0`.

Comment: Thx, Richard it worked I have one more question we are using GA for our website. This blocks all traffic which this kind of URIs but is there a better way to block this kind of DDoS attacks ?

Comment: You should maybe take a look over on Server Fault. They are more likely to understand these kinds of issues.