# How to create a Rewrite Rule to change a URL without date to one with date

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx

Is it possible to right a Rewrite Rule on Nginx that can convert a URL that does not have a date in it to one that does?

We are trying to migrate a website from a custom CMS to WordPress and want to build a 301 redirect from their old URL structure to the new WordPress one.

For example:

```
www.website.com/category/id/slug
```

needs to become:

```
www.website.com/category/yyyy/mm/dd/id/slug
```

Comment: Wordpress have setting in the admin dashboard to write permalinks

Comment: I understand that, we have no problem with the permalinks and that is setup. Their previous website has been running for over 4-5 years and Google has indexed them. We want to be able to do 301 redirects from those old URLs to the new URL structure.

Comment: If you have a lot of rewrites, and no obvious pattern, you could use a `map` directive. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49191594/nginx-rewrite-a-lot-2000-of-urls-with-parameters/49192527#49192527).