# NGINX rewrite rule doesn't match with REGEX (.+)

Tags: regex, nginx, parameters, url-rewriting, rules

We are trying to rewrite a link like this:

https://example.com/some/thing/?tx_career_view%5BjobUid%5D=12&tx_career_view%5Baction%5D=show&tx_career_view%5Bcontroller%5D=Job&cHash=2d8595af0dfc0bf1e8b75d88849f

Our rule looks like this:

```
rewrite ^/some/thing/(.+)   /some/where/else/ permanent;
```

In https://regex101.com/ it says our REGEX matches, but NGINX doesn't rewrite.

Comment: The query string (anything from the `?` onwards) is not part of the normalised URI used to match `location` and `rewrite` rules. If you have a complex URI to rewrite, you could try something like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49191594/nginx-rewrite-a-lot-2000-of-urls-with-parameters/49192527#49192527).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @RichardSmith pointed out, the URL arguments are not matched against (as in, for your URL, it is `/some/thing/`). Since you want to rewrite for any arguments, simply use:

```
rewrite ^/some/thing/  /some/where/else/ permanent;
```