# How to rewrtite in nginx URI with a Question Mark

Tags: regex, nginx, url-rewriting, webserver

Iam trying with nginx a rewrite a URI with a Question Mark ?
How can I escape a question mark?

The rewrite works, if I use a test URI without a "?".
But with one I got a 404

```
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

        root /var/www/html;

    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name example.com;

    #rewrite [^\/]+\/get\.php\?username=([^\&]+)&password=([^\&]+).*$ http://$host:8080/server/get_user_videolist?username=$1:password=$2 permanent;

    rewrite ^/get.phpusername=TEST123&password=SECRET123 http://$host:8080/server/get_user_chlist?username=TEST123:password=SECRET123;

    rewrite ^/get.php?Fusername=TEST123&password=SECRET123 http://$host:8080/server/get_user_chlist?username=TEST123:password=SECRET123;

}
```

My expected output should from first URL to second URL

```
http://example.com/get.php?username=TEST123&password=SECRET123

->

http://example.com:8080/server/get_user_chlist?username=TEST123:password=Secret123
```

error.log

```
2019/09/19 22:12:15 [error] 7059#7059: *183 open() "/var/www/html/get.php" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: *.*.*.*, server: example.com, request: "GET /get.php?username=TEST123&password=SECRET123 HTTP/1.1", host: "example.com"
```

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49191594/nginx-rewrite-a-lot-2000-of-urls-with-parameters/49192527#49192527).

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it by myself
http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html​

```
location / {
if ($args ~* "/?username=([a-zA-Z0-9]+)&password=([a-zA-Z0-9]+)") {
        set $username $1;
        set $password $2;
        rewrite ^ http://$host:8080/server/get_user_chlist?username=$username:password=$password? last;
    }
}
```