# nginx redirect - urls with parameters

Tags: nginx, redirect

I have included the following lines in my nginx_config file:

```
location = /xalia/ps/1/ {
  return 301 /xalia;
}
location = /xalia/ps/1/?type=1 {
  return 301 /xalia/monterna;
}
```

First redirection works ok.

But `/xalia/ps/1/?type=1` redirects to `/xalia` instead of `/xalia/monterna`.

How can I fix this?

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49191594/nginx-rewrite-a-lot-2000-of-urls-with-parameters/49192527#49192527).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
location = /xalia/ps/1/ {
    # Rewrite
    if ($args ~* "type=1") {
        rewrite .* /xalia/moderna permanent;
    }
    rewrite .* /xalia permanent;
}
```