# htaccess to nginx url redirection script (phpbb to xenforo)

Tags: .htaccess, nginx, redirect, phpbb, xenforo

I have these htaccess rules for redirecting phpbb urls to xenforos friendly urls

```
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)t=([0-9]+)(&|$) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^viewtopic\.php$ /threads/%2/? [L,R=301,NC]

    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} f=(\d+)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(viewforum\.php|viewtopic\.php)$ /forums/%1/? [L,R=301,NC]

    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)p=([0-9]+)(&|$) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^viewtopic\.php$ /posts/%2/? [L,R=301,NC]
```

which redirects phpbb urls to xenforo friendly urls like

```
"/viewtopic.php?t=X" will redirect to "/threads/X/" and
"/viewtopic.php?p=X" will redirect to "/posts/X/"
```

etc

What would its equivalent be in nginx? I tried online converters and even Plesk htaccess to nginx rules, no luck.

Plesk outputs this

```
if ($args ~* "(^|&)t=([0-9]+)(&|$)"){
    set $rule_0 1$rule_0;
    set $bref_2 $2;
    set $bref_undefined $undefined;
}
if ($rule_0 = "1"){
    rewrite ^/viewtopic\.php$ /threads/$bref_2/? permanent;
}
```

But it doesn't work. Help please.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49191594/nginx-rewrite-a-lot-2000-of-urls-with-parameters/49192527#49192527).

Answer (score 1):

Someone on the xenforo forum helped. I edited his script to make it work. This is the Nginx rewrite rule that works

```
if ($query_string ~* "(^|&)t=([0-9]+)(&|$)"){  
rewrite ^/viewtopic\.php$ /threads/$arg_t/? redirect;  }

if ($query_string ~* "f=(\d+)$"){  
rewrite ^/(viewforum\.php|viewtopic\.php)$ /forums/$arg_f/? redirect;  }

if ($query_string ~* "(^|&)p=([0-9]+)(&|$)"){  
rewrite ^/viewtopic\.php$ /posts/$arg_p/? redirect;  }
```