# NGINX 301 redirect using query argument value

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, nginx-config

I want to redirect **example.com/?lang=en** to **example.com/en/**.

I am using Python Django and my server running Plesk / Nginx.

I try to redirect on my webpage like this. But it's don't work;

```
rewrite ^/?lang=en$ /en/ redirect;
```

But if i remove question mark rewrite is worked.

I tried many methods but I couldn't find a solution.

Thank You.

Comment: `rewrite` matches its regular expression against a normalised URI which does not include the `?` or the query string which follows it. You could use a solution similar [to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49191594/nginx-rewrite-a-lot-2000-of-urls-with-parameters/49192527#49192527).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most simple is

```
if ($arg_lang = en) {
    return 301 /en$uri;
}
```

However if you'd have any other query arguments, they would lost with this redirection rule. To preserve all the other query arguments you can do the following:

```
if ($args ~ (.*)(^|&)lang=en(\2|$)&?(.*)) {
    set $args $1$3$4;
    return 301 /en$uri$is_args$args;
}
```

To support several languages the first solution came to mind is

```
if ($args ~ (.*)(^|&)lang=([^&]*)(\2|$)&?(.*)) {
    set $args $1$4$5;
    return 301 /$3$uri$is_args$args;
}
```

However if you'd have some malformed `lang` query argument value it would lead to redirection to non-existent page. To filter `lang` values for supported languages only you can use the [`map`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map) directive:

```
map $arg_lang $prefix {
    en    /en;
    de    /de;
    ...
    # if none matched, value of $prefix variable would be an empty string
}
map $args $stripped_args {
    # remove "lang" query argument if exists
    ~(.*)(^|&)lang=[^&]*(\2|$)&?(.*)  $1$3$4;
    default                           $args;
}
server {
    ...
    if ($prefix) {
        set $args $stripped_args;
        return 301 $prefix$uri$is_args$args;
    }
    ...
}
```

If your URI language prefix is the same as the `lang` query argument value (or can be derived from it through some regular expression), the first `map` block could be simplified:

```
map $arg_lang $prefix {
    ~^(en|de|...)$    /$1;
}
```

**Update**

As OP states, there could be a caveat when we've got a request like `example.com/de/some/path/?lang=en` which would be redirected to non-existent page `example.com/en/de/some/path/`. To avoid it we could define additional `map` block and strip the language prefix from the URI:

```
map $arg_lang $prefix {
    ~^(en|de|...)$    /$1;
}
map $args $stripped_args {
    # remove "lang" query argument if exists
    ~(.*)(^|&)lang=[^&]*(\2|$)&?(.*)  $1$3$4;
    default                           $args;
}
map $uri $stripped_uri {
    # remove language prefix from URI if one exists
    ~^/(en|de|...)(/.*)$  $2;
    default               $uri;
}
server {
    ...
    if ($prefix) {
        set $args $stripped_args;
        return 301 $prefix$stripped_uri$is_args$args;
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Ivan Its awesome answer. Its work awesome. Thanks a lot! I use your several languages solution and its work perfect. I just ask something. ex: example.com/?lang=en working perfect. but example.com/de/something1/somethin2/something3/?lang=en redirect to example.com/en/de/something1.... so its meaning 404 page. how can i push just change /de/ section on the your several languages solution? thank you so much!

Comment: @Aytek You're right, I didn't thought about this situation, check an update to the answer.

Comment: You are awesome. Thanks a lot! Its work but its working like this: example.com/fr/something1/something2?lang=en change to  example.com/en/fr/something1/something2... but after this try example.com/en/fr/something1/something2?lang=de its turn to example.com/de/fr/something1/something2... i dont know maybe its problem on my django. you can check my website onlinepoll.me (also i want to added your name about>thanks section // if you say okay ofc)

Comment: @Aytek Maybe this redirect got cached by your browser? Clear your browser cache or try it from incognito window. / of course you can )

Comment: Ivan sorry its my fault, i pass to add other lang to en|de|... section. its worked now awesome. Thanks a lot. This helped me a lot. I add everyone who helped me with my project on the thank you page. If you have permission, I want add you.

Comment: @Aytek Glad to hear everything is worked as expected now. Of course you can add my name if you want :)

Comment: I added :) https://onlinepoll.me/en/about-us/ Thank you so much again!

Comment: @Aytek I added some optimization to the answer, you could check an edit history if you're interested.