# nginx rewrite not getting the entire url

Tags: nginx, redirect, url-rewriting

I'm trying to implement nginx rewrite rules for the following situtation : Request

`/config-manager/getConfig?applicationId=tweetcasterandV2.xml` should be redirected to

`/myPath/tweetcasterandV2.xml`

I've set rewrite_log on for my server, created following rules:

```
    location /config-manager {
      rewrite ^/config-manager/getConfig?applicationId=(.*)$  /myPath/$1  last;
    }

    location /myPath
    {
      root   /usr/share/nginx/html/myPath;
      index  index.html index.htm;
    }
```

but when I do the request, I get 404 Not Found error from server. The error log contains the following:

```
root@60ade49e127b:/var/log/nginx# cat host.error.log
2020/10/24 00:20:58 [notice] 15#15: *1 "^/config-manager/getConfig?applicationId=(.*)$" does not match "/config-manager/getConfig", client: 172.17.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /config-manager/getConfig?applicationId=tweetcasterandV2.xml HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:8080"
2020/10/24 00:20:58 [error] 15#15: *1 open() "/etc/nginx/html/config-manager/getConfig" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.17.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /config-manager/getConfig?applicationId=tweetcasterandV2.xml HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:8080"
root@60ade49e127b:/var/log/nginx#
```

It's like rewrite is only getting a partial string and failing to match? I've seen tutorial where this is supposed to work. Is there a special parameter I need to set for nginx to pass the entire URL to rewrite?

Thanks.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49191594/nginx-rewrite-a-lot-2000-of-urls-with-parameters/49192527#49192527)

Answer (score 0):

Query string is not a subject to test with `location` or `rewrite` directives, they work with the normalized URI which doesn't include a query string. However you can do something like

```
location /config-manager {
    rewrite ^ /myPath/$arg_applicationId last;
}
```

You can also take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62656217/nginx-301-redirect-using-query-argument-value/62664422#62664422) answer.