# convert htaccess to nginx redirect

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, nginx-location, nginx-config

I have an apache redirect rule as below

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} Product.html
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ProdNo=([^&]+)&Brand=([^&]+)
RewriteRule Product.html https://www.example.com/US/en/product/%2-%1? [R=301,L]
```

Need to convert into nginx redirect, i tried a lot but unable to make it success
wanna try with map directive as i want to use with bulk redirections with map files
can any help me on this

Comment: Maybe something like: `location = /Product.html { return 301 https://www.example.com/US/en/product/$arg_Brand-$arg_ProdNo; }`

Comment: @RichardSmith excellent this is working if we configure with nginx location , have any idea about how to configure with map directives or map files

Comment: And also want to redirect same destination with another location like /product/search/detils.do? will this work ```location = /Product.html | /product/search/detils.do{ return 301 https://www.example.com/US/en/product/$arg_Brand-$arg_ProdNo; }```

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49191594/nginx-rewrite-a-lot-2000-of-urls-with-parameters/49192527#49192527). You could add a line to the map like: `/Product.html  https://www.example.com/US/en/product/$arg_Brand-$arg_ProdNo;`

Comment: @RichardSmith Awesome all are working as expected and i need one more help need to convert below rules as well ```RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} catalog/ProductDetail.do$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} N4=([^&]+)\|([^&]+)
RewriteRule catalog/ProductDetail.do /US/en/product/%2-%1? [R=301,L]```

```RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} catalog/search$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} interface=CAS[\+No\.|%20No\.]|&term=([^&]+)
RewriteRule catalog/search /US/en/search/CAS-%1? [R=301,L]```