# How can I do an nginx redirect while dissecting the query string?

Tags: nginx

Some other website has copied and pasted HTML from mine years ago as a way to embed part of my offering on their pages, and now I get errors when people click through on outdated links. So I want to redirect from

```
https://www.example.com/entity1234/seo-friendly-title-here/?item=3
```

to

```
https://www.example.com/entity1234/seo-friendly-title-here/filters/item3/
```

I tried

```
location ~ "^(.*)/entity([0-9]+)/([^/]+)/\?item=([0-9]+)$" {
    return 301 $1/entity$2/$3/filters/item$4/;
}
```

But as you know and I now know, the query string is stripped from the URL when matching on a location block.  So how should I perform this?

Searching other questions seemed to show me examples where I could append the whole querystring to the redirect with the $args variable, or use an if condition do something, but "if is evil", etc.  Please show me the correct way!

Comment: `if` in a `location` is evil when used incorrectly. As [the documentation](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) shows, `return 301` within an `if` is always safe. If you have one redirect, use `if ($request_uri = "/entity1234/seo-friendly-title-here/?item=3") { return 301 ...; }`. If there is more than one, use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49191594/nginx-rewrite-a-lot-2000-of-urls-with-parameters/49192527#49192527).

Comment: Many more than one - thanks!

Comment: Hmm, I can't seem to get regex working inside map, maybe it doesn't work and this isn't possible.  I think I'm just going to write the 2 lines of php that will fix this in a moment, rather than waste more time on it.

Comment: See [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/930145/nginx-redirect-based-on-query-string-parameters/930187#930187), but I can't argue against using the tools you're most familiar with.