# nginx: load 404 page if location is not matched with given url

Tags: php, nginx, http-status-code-404

in `nginx.conf` I have used this

`try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;`

so that when user type any url the index.php will load.

but now I have some list of url. like `[blog, contact, faq]`

so when user hit anything out of that url. for example, `/test` I want to display the 404 page.

how can I achieve that?

here is the location block

```
location / {
             auth_basic "Restricted Content";
             auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
             try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;

         }
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's a long list, [use a `map`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49191594/nginx-rewrite-a-lot-2000-of-urls-with-parameters/49192527#49192527), but if its a short list, add extra [`location` rules](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location):

```
location = /test { return 404; }
```

If you want these rules to be subject to your `auth_basic`, either nest them within the `location /` block, or if possible, move the `auth_basic` statements into the outer block.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`map`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html) block, e.g.:

```
map $uri $correct_route {
    /blog    1;
    /contact 1;
    /faq     1;
    # default value will be an empty string
}
server {
    ...
    auth_basic "Restricted Content";
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ @check_route;
    }
    location @check_route {
        if ($correct_route) { rewrite ^ /index.php last; }
        return 404;
    }
    ...
}
```