# NGINX rewrite URL with query param

Tags: nginx, redirect, url-rewriting, kubernetes-helm

I want to  redirect an URL request when it arrives at a specific location. The target URL is a whole different site + the value of the original request's query parameter.

I tried the `return` directive with variables like `$uri` `$request_uri` `$args` `$arg_<myarg>` etc., but the whole query string was added to the target URL in every attempt.

Than I moved towards `rewrite`, but the regex capture group I'm trying to use isn't working. This is my current syntax:

```
location ~ /search-redirection?keyword=.* {
   rewrite ^keyword=(.*)$ {{ .Values.frontend.environment.TARGET_URL }}$1 redirect;
}
```

(This all happens in a Helm configmap, and the TARGET_URL is ending with: search-results?q=, that is why I only need the param's value.)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Neither `location` nor `rewrite` can test the query string part of a URL. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49191594/nginx-rewrite-a-lot-2000-of-urls-with-parameters/49192527#49192527).

Comment: Thanks for replying! I may be wrong, but that answer doesn't actually match my problem. I basically want to achieve this:
location /product {
        rewrite ^/product(.*)$ https://www.newsite.com/$1 redirect;
    }
(https://ubiq.co/tech-blog/how-to-redirect-location-to-another-domain-in-nginx/)
I made my research multiple times and it seems doable.