# Regex match URL with a ? in it that doesn't operate as a query string identifier

Tags: regex, nginx, redirect

I've got a URL like this:

https://example.co.uk/?/blog/article/my-blog-post

And I want to redirect it to in nginx/using regex

https://example.co.uk/blog/my-blog-post

And nothing I do seems to be able to match that ?

I've tried these 2:

/?/blog/article/my-blog-post
/\?/blog/article/my-blog-post

And it just doesn't seem to see the ? when it does this matching.

My other issue is there *may* be other blog posts with this stupid ? in the url. So in an ideal world, I'd like a rule that matches any URL like that and redirects to a new URL pattern, so like the following.

https://example.co.uk/?/blog/article/any-blog-post

To

https://example.co.uk/blog/any-blog-post

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: What application/framework/language are you using?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Well, nginx or regex would be the place to handle this! Thanks!

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49192527/4862445).