# Doing bulk permanent redirects in NGINX

Tags: nginx, redirect, bulk

I need to permanently redirect 30+ pages from one website to another. Specifically, I need to map/redirect individual pages from one URL to new versions of the same pages on a different server, like this:

```
https://currentserver/policy/academic-honesty/ > https://newserver/policy/academic-honesty/
https://currentserver/policy/academic-leave/ > https://newserver/policy/academic-leave/
https://currentserver/policy/academic-standing/ > https://newserver/policy/academic-standing/
```

Is there a way to do this other than doing 30+ individual rewrite rules for each page in our conf file?

Thanks for any suggestions

I am new to NGINX and so I started doing the individual rewrites rules for each page than thought maybe there's a better way. I did reach the NGINX help file for this but I didn't see anything that specified doing this for individual pages that needed to be redirected to new individual pages.

Comment: If there's a pattern to the 30+ pages, use a regular expression. The [rewrite directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) requires a regular expression as the first parameter. Otherwise, [use a map](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49192527/4862445).

Comment: What is your current config? 30 locations for every URL?